# Are there better alternatives rathet than joining a table twice for having one record for a specific column in the output?

Tags: oracle, query-performance, oracle-11g-r2, performance-tuning

I have two tables with below structures:

```
create table TABLE_LC
( lc_num   NUMBER,
  brn_code NUMBER,
  brn_role NUMBER)

create table BRN
( brn_code NUMBER,
  brn_name VARCHAR2(50))
```

Some example data for each table is this:

```
"TABLE_LC":

lc_num    |  brn_code  |  brn_role
------------------------------------
  1       |     1      |  1010  
  1       |     2      |  2020  


"BRN":

brn_code  |  brn_name  
---------------------
  1       |   BAHAR    
  2       |    KAJ
```

I need To have `one record for each lc_num` in TABLE_LC and the desired output based on the given tables and data is this:

```
lc_num    |  Advising_Bank  |  Issuing_Bank
-------------------------------------------
  1       |     BAHAR       |  KAJ
```

What I've written is below query which gives me the correct output,considering the fact that we know `brn_role=1010 represents Advising Bank` and `brn_role=2020 represents Issuing Bank`

```
select t1.lc_num, 
       t2.brn_name "Advising Bank", 
       t4.brn_name "Issuing bank"
  from TABLE_LC t1
 inner join BRN t2
    on t1.brn_code = t2.brn_code
   and t1.brn_role = 1010
 inner join TABLE_LC t3
    on t3.lc_num = t1.lc_num
 inner join BRN t4
    on t4.brn_code = t3.brn_code
   and t3.brn_role = 2020
```

As you can see, I have joined the base table twice, I want to know if there are better ways of  getting the desired output ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a technique which allows to use one `BRN` table copy - but it cannot be referred to as "better way" (it uses grouping and conditional aggregation). The query which you use now is optimal, especially when it is indexed optimally.

Comment: @Akina Thanks. I thought that the way I used is not that professional and there must be better ways. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: :) pre-optimization is evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better?  It depends.

If the primary key of `TABLE_LC` is `(lc_num, brn_role)` then you *could* do something like this:

```
SELECT
  lc_Num
 ,MAX
    (
      CASE
        WHEN brn_role = 1010 THEN brn_name
        ELSE NULL
      END
    ) AS Advising_Bank
 ,MAX
    (
      CASE
        WHEN brn_role = 2020 THEN brn_name
        ELSE NULL
      END
    ) AS Issuing_Bank
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      LC.lc_num
     ,LC.brn_role
     ,LC.brn_code
     ,BRN.brn_name
    FROM
      TABLE_LC LC
    INNER JOIN
      BRN BRN
        ON BRN.brn_code = LC.brn_code
  ) x
GROUP BY
  lc_num
```

Which, you'll note:

1. Is about the same amount of code
2. Is harder to understand
3. Even though it only performs one join, it still might not produce the best query plan, depending on whether or not `TABLE_LC` is index-organized.

You could also use [PIVOT](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html), but again, probably not that much time savings and you're left with the problem of dealing with goofy column names.

Joins on primary keys/appropriate indexes are generally not that expensive, so avoiding them only makes sense in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed my query to this and it gives me the result I want :

```
select t1.lc_num, 
       t2.brn_name "Advising Bank", 
       t3.brn_name "Issuing bank"
  from TABLE_LC t1
 left join BRN t2
    on t1.brn_code = t2.brn_code
   and t1.brn_role = 1010
 left join BRN t3
    on t1.brn_code = t3.brn_code
   and t1.brn_role = 2020
```

Actually there is no need to have another `inner join TABLE_LC`. Instead I changed all inner joins to `left join` and I think this approach is better than the others, performance wise.